# Where are an e-mail's headers in the MS Outlook Object Model?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

With an e-mail open in Outlook with [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) installed, I found the headers of the e-mail at:

```
OutlookSpy > IMessage > GetProps > PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS_W  (the last property in the list)
```

[That is a MAPI property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagtransportmessageheaders-canonical-property) and I don't see any corresponding property in the [Outlook Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/outlook/object-model). I figure the headers have to be somewhere in the model. Where are they?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve any MAPI property (well, almost) using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor`.[GetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor.getproperty). The DASL property name (OutlookSpy shows it) for `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS_W` is `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F"`

Comment: Yeah, but are the headers actually not included in the Outlook Object Model?

Comment: The Outlook object model doesn't provide all the properties available via Extended MAPI.

Comment: There are quite a few things not included in OOM. That is why MS exposed `MailItem.PropertyAccessor` in Outlook 2007. That property will not be always present - it is only available on messages received from SMTP. Not on sent messages, and not on messages received from other EX mailboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Not all properties are available in the Outlook object model. Lowl-level properties are available using the [PropertyAccessor.GetProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor.getproperty) method which returns an Object that represents the value of the property specified by `SchemaName`. For getting transport headers you may use the following code:

```
Sub DemoPropertyAccessorGetProperty() 
 Dim PropName, Header As String 
 Dim oMail As Object 
 Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor 
 'Get first item in the inbox 
 Set oMail = _ 
 Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items(1) 
 'PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS 
 PropName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E" 
 'Obtain an instance of PropertyAccessor class 
 Set oPA = oMail.PropertyAccessor 
 'Call GetProperty 
 Header = oPA.GetProperty(PropName) 
 Debug.Print (Header) 
End Sub
```

But in some cases you would need to use Extended MAPI for getting low-level properties because the OOM applies its own restrictions to them.